# Bootstrap show tab doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I have this code in my `footer`:

```
<script>

    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    if(getParameterByName('related') == 'true'){
        document.querySelector("#atTab > li.active > a").scrollIntoView();
        jQuery(function () {
            jQuery('.nav-tabs a[href="#tab-related"]').tab('show');
        })  
    }


</script>
```

And if you call a webpage with the get parameter `?related=true` then this the if clause should be get executed. It also gets executed. You can see that, becasue the window scrolls. But the tab `#tab-related` doesn't open. I also don't get an error... But if you perform this code in the console:

```
jQuery('.nav-tabs a[href="#tab-related"]').tab('show');
```

... it works. How can that be and how can I fix that?

Here you can test it: https://radlvoo.de/produkt/winora-senegal-damen-2017-rh-groesse-51/?related=true

Kind regards

Comment: But I run it (show Tab) after everything is loaded mit jQuery ready

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `jQuery(function(){//this is called when DOMContentLoaded fires})`. Still, if you paste the if-statement in console, all the right stuff happens. So it still seems to have something to do with order of execution.

Comment: Ah yes, apologies, I missed the location of the handler within the `if` statement

Comment: I edit it, doesn't make a difference

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: To verify that you have a problem with the order of execution, wrap the if-statement in a setTimeout, for let's say 1000ms. You should now see the effect 1s after the page is loaded. Note, it's not a solution.